# Is it possible to put pi into terms of rationals

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, pi

I don't know of that is the correct terminology but by this I mean in the way that $\phi$ can be put into the equation $(1+\sqrt 5)/2$. I have heard that it has never been achieved but I was wondering if there was anything to show that it was imposible. If so, would anyone mind providing links to studies, webpages, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  $\dfrac{\pi}{1}$

Comment: If you mean in a form of an [algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number), note that [the transcendence of $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#The_transcendence_of_%CF%80) has been proven, so it's not algebraic.

Comment: Maybe it depends on what you mean exactly, but what about $\frac\pi1$? If you’re wanting to write $\pi$ using some sequence of addition, multiplication, or roots of integers, then the answer is “No” because $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: @Clayton thanks for you comment but I meant not as an obvious divisor, such as π/1, 2π/2 or 400π/20^2